# Questions on Mellin convolutions involving $g(x)=\log(x)$

Tags: integration, logarithms, convolution, mellin-transform

The questions below assume the following definitions of the Mellin transform and associated convolutions.

**(1)** $\quad F(s)=\mathcal{M}_x[f(x)](s)=\int\limits_0^\infty f(x)\,x^{s-1}dx$

**(2)** $\quad f(x)*_{\mathcal{M}_1}g(x)=\int\limits_0^\infty f(x)\,g\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\frac{dx}{x}$

**(3)** $\quad f(x)*_{\mathcal{M}_2}g(x)=\int\limits_0^\infty f(x)\,g(y\,x)\frac{dx}{x}$

Assume the following function definitions.

**(4)** $\quad f_1(x)=\sqrt{x}\cos(2\,\pi\,a\,x)\,,\quad a>0$

**(5)** $\quad f_2(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\cos(2\,\pi\,a\,x)\,,\quad a>0$

**(6)** $\quad g(x)=\log(x)$

I've used Mathematica to evaluate the Mellin convolution $f_1(x)*_{\mathcal{M}_1}\log(x)$ both via the $MellinConvolve$ function and via the $Integrate$ function which (after some simplifications and assuming $y>0$) provide consistent results as illustrated below.

**(7)** $\quad f_1(x)*_{\mathcal{M}_1}\log(x)=MellinConvolve\left[f_1(x),\log(x),x,y\right]=\frac{\log\left(64\,\pi^2\,a^2\,y^2\right)+\pi+2\,\gamma}{4\sqrt{a}},\quad a>0$

**(8)** $\quad f_1(x)*_{\mathcal{M}_1}\log(x)=\int_0^\infty f_1(x)\frac{\log\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}{x}\,dx=\frac{\log(64)+2\log(\pi\,a\,y)+\pi+2\,\gamma}{4\sqrt{a}}\,,\quad a>0$

I've also evaluated the alternate Mellin convolution of $f_2(x)*_{\mathcal{M}_2}\log(x)$ which  (again after some simplifications) provides the following result.

**(9)** $\quad f_2(x)*_{\mathcal{M}_2}\log(x)=\int_0^\infty f_2(x)\log(y\,x)\,dx=-\frac{\log(64)+2\log\left(\frac{\pi\,a}{y}\right)+\pi+2\,\gamma}{4\sqrt{a}}\,,\quad a>0\land y>0$

I suspect the results illustrated in (7), (8), and (9) above may be incorrect, but haven't yet been able to confirm it.

**Question 1**: Are the results illustrated in (7), (8), and (9) above correct?

**Question 2**: If so, what are the derivations of these results? Can these results be proven via integration by parts?

**Question 3**: If not, what are the correct results for the Mellin convolution $f_1(x)*_{\mathcal{M}_1}\log(x)$ illustrated in (7) and (8) above and the alternate Mellin convolution $f_2(x)*_{\mathcal{M}_2}\log(x)$ illustrated in (9) above?

I've explored validation of the convolutions above via the following relationships, but note that the Mellin transform of $\log(x)$ is undefined.

**(10)** $\quad\mathcal{M}_x[f(c\,x)](s)=c^{-s}\mathcal{M}_x[f(x)](s)$

**(11)** $\quad\mathcal{M}_x[f(x)*_{\mathcal{M}_1}g(x)](s)=\mathcal{M}_x[f(x)](s)\,\mathcal{M}_x[g(x)](s)=F(s)\,G(s)$

Assume the simpler function $f_0(x)$ defined in (12) below (analogous to $f_1(x)$ defined in (4) above) and associated Mathematica evaluations of the Mellin convolution and Mellin transform illustrated in (13) and (14) below.

**(12)** $\quad f_0(x)=\sqrt{x}\cos(x)$

**(13)** $\quad f_0(x)*_{\mathcal{M}_1}\log(x)=MellinConvolve\left[f_0(x),\log (x),x,y\right]\\$ $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}(2\log(y)+\log(16)+\pi+2\,\gamma)$

**(14)** $\quad F_0(s)=\mathcal{M}_x[f_0(x)](s)=\frac{1}{2}(2\,s-1)\cos\left(\frac{\pi\,s}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\,\Gamma\left(s-\frac{1}{2}\right),\quad-\frac{1}{2}<\Re(s)<\frac{1}{2}$

The result of the Mellin convolution illustrated in (13) above can be rewritten as follows.

**(15)** $\quad f_0(x)*_{\mathcal{M}_1}\log(x)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \log \left(4 e^{\gamma +\frac{\pi }{2}} y\right)$

Relationship (10) above can be used to evaluate the Mellin transform of (15) above as follows.

**(16)** $\quad\mathcal{M}_x[f_0(x)*_{\mathcal{M}_1}\log(x)](s)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(4\,e^{\gamma+\frac{\pi}{2}}\right)^{-s}\mathcal{M}_y[\log (y)](s)$

The relationship (11) above and the results illustrated in (14) and (16) above imply the following.

**(17)** $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(4\,e^{\gamma+\frac{\pi}{2}}\right)^{-s}\mathcal{M}_y[\log (y)](s)=\frac{1}{2}(2\,s-1)\cos\left(\frac{\pi\,s}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\,\Gamma\left(s-\frac{1}{2}\right)\,\mathcal{M}_x[\log(x)](s)$

**(18)** $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(4\,e^{\gamma+\frac{\pi}{2}}\right)^{-s}=\frac{1}{2}(2\,s-1)\cos\left(\frac{\pi\,s}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\,\Gamma\left(s-\frac{1}{2}\right)$

The left and right sides of (18) above are only equal at $s=0$ which implies the Mathematica evaluation of the Mellin convolution in (13) above is incorrect.

Comment: What is $\gamma$?

Comment: $\gamma$ is the Euler–Mascheroni constant (also called Euler's constant) 0.5772... (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html).

Comment: wonderful I've seen it before and this is a wonderful sighting of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a bunch of complex analysis.

For $a > 0$ : $$ \int_0^\infty x^{s-1} e^{-ax}dx= \int_0^\infty (y/a)^{s-1} e^{-y}d(y/a) = a^{-s} \int_0^\infty y^{s-1}e^{-y}dy = a^{-s} \Gamma(s)=e^{-s \log a} \Gamma(s)$$

Note $ \int_0^\infty x^{s-1} e^{-ax}dx-e^{-s \log a} \Gamma(s)$ is analytic for $\Re(a) > 0$, thus by analytic continuation, or the isolated zero theorem, $ \int_0^\infty x^{s-1} e^{-ax}dx-e^{-s \log a} \Gamma(s)=0$ stays true for $\Re(a) > 0$.

For $\Re(s) \in (0,1)$, $ \int_0^\infty x^{s-1} e^{-ax}dx$ is continuous in $a, \Re(a) \ge 0, a \ne 0$. Thus for $b > 0$

$$ \int_0^\infty x^{s-1} \cos(bx) dx=b^{-s}  \int_0^\infty x^{s-1} \cos(x) dx\\= \lim_{a \to i} b^{-s}\int_0^\infty x^{s-1} \frac{e^{-ax}}{2} dx+\lim_{a \to -i}b^{-s} \int_0^\infty x^{s-1} \frac{e^{-ax}}{2} dx  \\ = \lim_{a \to i}b^{-s}\frac{e^{-s \log a} \Gamma(s)}{2}+\lim_{a \to -i}b^{-s}\frac{e^{-s \log a} \Gamma(s)}{2}\\ = b^{-s}\frac{e^{-s i\pi/2} \Gamma(s)+e^{s i\pi/2} \Gamma(s)}{2}=b^{-s}\cos(\pi s/2) \Gamma(s)$$

Finally for $b > 0, \Re(s) \in (0,1)$
$$ \int_0^\infty x^{s-1} \cos(bx)(\log x) dx = \frac{d}{ds}\int_0^\infty x^{s-1} \cos(bx) dx =\frac{d}{ds}b^{-s}\cos( \pi s/2) \Gamma(s)$$

Comment: In your answer you provide derivations of the Mellin transforms of $e^{-a\,x}$, $\cos(b\,x)$, and $\cos(b\,x)\log(x)$, but my question was about Mellin convolutions versus Mellin transforms. With respect to the Mellin convolution in (4) and (5) above, the Mellin transform of the Mellin convolution $f_1(x)*_{\mathcal{M}}g(x)$ is the product of the Mellin transforms of $f_1(x)$ and $g(x)$.

Comment: The Mellin transform of $f_1(x)$ is $\mathcal{M}_x\left[f_1(x)\right](s)=(2 \pi )^{\frac{1}{2}-s} a^{\frac{1}{2}-s} \sin \left(\frac{1}{4} (2 \pi s+\pi )\right) \Gamma \left(s-\frac{1}{2}\right)$ where $\frac{1}{2}<\Re(s)<\frac{3}{2}$, but the Mellin transforms of $g(x)$ and $f_1(x)*_{\mathcal{M}}g(x)$ are both undefined, so I haven't been able to make much sense of the convolution $f_1(x)*_{\mathcal{M}}g(x)$ in terms of Mellin transforms.

Comment: @StevenClark What you say about the Mellin transform of $\log x$ and $f_1 \ast \log x$ doesn't make sense. The Fourier transform of $\log e^u$ exists in the sense of distributions. Don't you see how the last line of my answer helps for $\int_0^\infty x^{-1/2} \cos(bx) \log(y/x)dx$

Comment: When I attempted to derive the Mellin transform of $\log(x)$ from the Fourier transform of $\log(x)$, I obtained the result zero. I took another look at your answer and realized I could derive the Mellin convolution $f_1(x)*_{\mathcal{M}_1}\log(x)$ from the Mellin transform $\mathcal{M}_x[f_1(x)\,\log\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)](s)$, but the formula only converges for $Re(y)>0$ and $\Im(y)\ne 0$ which is the same problem I was having with the formulas derived from the terms illustrated in (7), (8), and (9) in my original question. I was hoping to derive a formula which converges for $\Im(y)=0$.

Comment: @StevenClark You are super boring. Your questions and your comments don't make any sense because you need to stop playing with mathematica and learn the Fourier inversion theorem and the Fourier transform of distributions. There is nothing else to say.

Comment: Perhaps you could enlighten me on the definition of the Mellin transform of $log(x)$.

Comment: @StevenClark $h_1(x) = 1$ doesn't have a Mellin transform, nor does $h_2(x)=\log x$.  But both $h_1(e^u), h_2(e^u)$ have a Fourier transform in the sense of distributions, for which the convolution theorem holds. Because they are functions, their Fourier transform is $\lim_{a \to \infty} \widehat{H_{l,a}}$ where $\widehat{H_{l,a}}(\omega) = \int_{-a}^a h_l(e^u)e^{-i \omega u} du$. See the comments to your previous questions for more precision.

Comment: Wake up. In a recent answer to my own question on which we exchanged numerous comments I illustrated the Mellin transform of 1 is $2\,\pi\,\delta(i\,s)$ which can be validated by evaluating the inverse Mellin transform $\frac{1}{2\,\pi\,i}\int\limits_{c-i\,\infty}^{c+i\,\infty}(2\,\pi\,\delta(i\,s))\,x^{-s}\,ds$ at $c=0$ with the variable substitution $s=-i\,t$ resulting in $\frac{1}{2\,\pi\,i}\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty}(2\,\pi\,\delta\,(t))\,x^{i\,t}\,i\,dt=x^0=1$.

Comment: @StevenClark No, this is not true, it doesn't work like that. $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(t) x^{it} dt = 1, x \ne 0$ is true with the appropriate definition of $\delta(t)$, but you can't replace $t$ by $is$. Then the Fourier transform of distributions is what you need to obtain that $\delta(t)$ is the inverse Fourier transform of $1$. Don't even try, you will never make sense to this topic without following what I say.

Comment: I didn't replace $t$ by $i\,s$, rather I replaced $s$ by $-i\,t$. I derived the inverse Mellin transform, not the forward Mellin transform, and it seems to me this derivation follows from basic properties of the $\delta(x)$ function such as $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(x)\,f(x)\,dx=f(0)$ where x is continuous at $x=0$. Mathematica evaluates $\frac{1}{2\,\pi\,i}\int\limits_{-i\,\infty}^{i\,\infty}(2\,\pi\,\delta(i\,s))\,x^{-s}\,ds$ as $1$ which seems to confirm my derivation, but then again I'm finding more and more cases where I can't necessarily trust Mathematica evaluations.

Comment: @StevenClark Why don't you follow what I say ? Your one and only one problem is to prove that $\lim_{a \to \infty} \int_{-a}^a e^{i k x} dk$ converges to $2\pi\delta(x)$ in the sense of distributions. All the rest is bullshit.

Comment: I disagree. Many results can be derived and understood from the basic properties of $\delta(x)$. I have proven the inverse Mellin transform of $2\pi\delta(i\,s)$ is $1$ by evaluating the associated integral. If you don't understand that $\int_{-i\,\infty}^{i\,\infty}f(i\,s)\,ds=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)\,i\,dt$, then there really isn't much I can do to convince you.

Comment: This result is an indirect proof that the Mellin transform of 1 is $2\pi\delta(i\,s)$. A direct proof of the forward transform is more difficult as you have suggested. I submitted a problem report to Wolfram, my analysis has been verified as correct, and the results have been forwarded to their implementation team.